# Expected value of index of the minimum element in an array

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

I'm stuck the following assignment:

What is the expected value of the index of the minimum element in an array of n distinct integer that are randomly ordered?

I think it should be something like:

$E(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{P_iX_i}$
where

$P_i$ is probability index-i contains the minimum value, so, $P_i = 1/n$.

But not sure what is $X_i$ in this case. 
I tried to make $X_i$  as random variable with value $1$ if index-i is the minimum value, or $0$ otherwise. But this results in a constant form, which does not seem right...

Any idea, guys? Many thanks.

Comment: The minimum is just as likely to be at $i$ as at $n+1-i$. So the mean is $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task asks for the *expected index* , so $X = i$ and we want to know $E(X)$.
$X = i$ means our experiment is:

> Randomly distribute $n$ integers in an array and our result $X$ is defined to be the array index of the smallest element in the array.

For convenience, we say the indices $i$ shall be in $\Omega = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, and the equal distribution gives $p_i = p(X = i) = \frac{1}{|\Omega|} = \frac{1}{n}$.
This gives
$$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{1}{n} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2}$$
for other index ranges, translate respectively.

Comment: Thanks, AlexR. So from your answer, $P_i = 1/n$ and $X_i = i$? But what does $X_i = i$ represents? Do you mind to elaborate more?

Comment: Yes. Does the elaboration suffice?

Comment: I guess I understand now :) Thanks, AlexR

Comment: @user350954 You're welcome :)